# How to use JWT token in the case of Social authentication. (Django)

Tags: python, django, jwt, social-authentication

Normally JWT flow is when enter Username and password it return a JWT token. using the token we can authenticate APIs.
But when we use social authentication how it will happen..?
When we use social authentication, for example google,
we clicks on login with google >> it give access >> redirect with authorisation code >> it gives open id details like email, first name, last name.
If any one have any idea please share.
Im using python django.